# How to apply a page style to a specific set of pages?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

I want to split my document in three parts.

The first part is the first document which has the style "First Page". The other ones have "Default". Now, I want the appendix to have the "Index" page style to allow different page numbering.

Alas, I am unable to only define a certain page set, namely in my case, page 9 to 18 to "Index". For some reason, all the pages get the "Index" page style. But I want page 2 to 8 to remain at their "Default" state. I also find weird that the first page remains at its "First page" style.

So how do I define only a certain page range to accept a different page style?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by editing the page line break and configuring it to have it be followed by the Index page style.